# Need regular expression for making text between * bold

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to bold the text between `*`, like `*bold*` I'm trying regular expressions in JavaScript but I don't know why its not working.

```
var bold = /\*(.*?)\*/gim;
var replacedText = replacedText.replace(bold, function($0,$1){
    return $1?$0:'<b>' + $0 + '</b>';
});
```

Thank you guys here is final Answer

**Edited**

```
var bold = /\*(.*?)\*/gim;
var replacedText = replacedText.replace(bold, function($0,$1){
    return $1 ? ('<b>' + $1 + '</b>') : $0;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The regex is OK, but your logic is not:

```
var replacedText = replacedText.replace(bold, function($0,$1){
    return $1 ? ('<b>' + $1 + '</b>') : $0;
});
```

The condition was inverted, and in any case you should be using `$1` when replacing instead of `$0` (the latter includes the asterisks).

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
function makeBold(id) {

  var re = /(\*)([^*]*)(\*)/g;

  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(re, '<b>$2</b>');
}
```

should get you started.